# Cmake : file is not copying

Tags: cmake, copy, makefile, fortran, fortran90

I work in a big project, which is written by Fortran. We build it with a help of CMake. I need to copy a file "plane.tsm", which is needed by function "test_tsmparser.F90", to the corresponding place in build directory. I already did it once for another function,  but now it doesn't work.

Corresponding CMakeList.txt :

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src)
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test)
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/utils/xml/sax)  

add_executable(test_tsmparser test_tsmparser.F90)

target_link_libraries(test_tsmparser testlib sax)

function (cm_export_file FILE DEST)
  if (NOT TARGET export-files)
    add_custom_target(export-files ALL COMMENT "Exporting files into build tree")
  endif (NOT TARGET export-files)
  get_filename_component(FILENAME "${FILE}" NAME)
  add_custom_command(TARGET export-files COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${DEST}/${FILENAME}")
  install(FILES "${FILE}" DESTINATION "${DEST}")
endfunction (cm_export_file)

cm_export_file("plane.tsm" "./")
```

Strangely for me, executable test_tsmparser is created, but file "plane.tsm" is not copied. What can it mean?

Maybe the problem is that exactly the same function is called by the other target before.

Tell me, if you need some more information, because I don't know what else is relevant.

Comment: Can you clarify what the intent of the target `export-files` is? Is it supposed to copy the file when built, without dependencies to other targets?

Comment: Yes, it should just copy the file I need into corresponding directory. I guess that the problem is that this target is already build for another copying, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared that I need just to change the names of the targets for this two CMakeLists.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: strange, but I had similar issue and names change helped. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a custom command which should produce an output, you should be using the `OUTPUT` signature of `add_custom_command()`, not the `TARGET` one:

```
function (cm_export_file FILE DEST)
  get_filename_component(FILENAME "${FILE}" NAME)
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${DEST}/${FILENAME}"
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE}"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${DEST}/${FILENAME}"
  )
  set(copiedFiles ${copiedFiles} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${DEST}/${FILENAME}" PARENT_SCOPE)
  install(FILES "${FILE}" DESTINATION "${DEST}")
endfunction (cm_export_file)
```

Then, once all the calls are done, create the custom target which will drive the commands:

```
add_custom_target(
  export-files ALL
  DEPENDS ${copiedFiles}
  COMMENT "Exporting files into build tree"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. So at which file and at which point I should add custom target export-files?

Comment: @TarasKucherenko It has to be in the same CMakeLists.txt, after all calls to `cm_export_file()`.

Comment: I need to copy a file for different folders, so I do it in different CMakeList files. Now I am getting next error :CMake Error at test/cases/tsm/CMakeLists.txt:28 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "export-files" because another
  target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom
  target created in source directory
  "/home/tk207547/src/splinelib/test/cases/iges".  See documentation for
  policy CMP0002 for more details.

Comment: @TarasKucherenko OK, then you could try going back to your original idea, but adding one of the mandatory `POST_BUILD`, `PRE_BUILD` or `PRE_LINK` (which you were missing).

Comment: I added word PRE_BUILD to the line : add_custom_command(TARGET export-files … ). Still just first call of this function copies a file, while second is not doing it

Comment: @TarasKucherenko Could be the directory issue again. Could you gather the source files to be copied from all directories (perhaps in a global property) and only create the custom target & commands at the top level once all subdirs are processed?